# how to access local storage in iOS on app startup

Tags: ios, cordova, local-storage

How do i access local storage in iOS? I need to do it in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. This is a cordova phonegap voip application. IOS sometimes restarts my app straight into the background.

I found this way to do it but it needs to be done in webViewDidFinishLoad:
https://getsatisfaction.com/application_craft/topics/reading_localstorage_from_ios_phonegap_objective_c

```
CDVLocalStorage *localStorage = [viewController.pluginObjects objectForKey:@"CDVLocalStorage"];
NSString *sidjs = @"localStorage['sid'];";
NSString* sid = [localStorage.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: sidjs];
NSLog(@"sid: %@", sid);
```

When i tried this in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions it returns an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the webViewDidFinishLoad, because localStorage lives inside the webView and if the webView didn't load the app you don't have localStorage yet, that's why you get empty strings.

If you want to use other storage available on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you have to use the native NSUserDefaults 
You can use this plugin to set the `NSUserDefaults` using javascript:
https://github.com/apla/me.apla.cordova.app-preferences/

So from javascript you do this:

```
var prefs = plugins.appPreferences;

prefs.store (ok, fail, 'key', 'value');
function ok (value) {}
function fail (error) {}
```

On the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` use

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults objectForKey:@"key"];
```

Comment: is there a storage option that doesn't involve the use of callbacks for the value and available on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? i have code structured like name = function(){ return window.localStorage.getItem("name");} I don't think this would work now with appPrefernces

Comment: Can i somehow load the web view during didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? I can initialize local storage with <param name="onload" value="true" /> in the config.xml. So there's a local storage and a web view object available during didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Comment: No, it's not possible, you need a native storage if you want to use it on didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and native storage needs callbacks if you use them from javascript